# Problem with Special Characters in jinja2 - Ç, É

Tags: python, jinja2

So I have a html file I'm working with both jinja and flask, but I'm having trouble with some characters as in the example:

```
<h1> Produção </h1>
```

When I run the layout.html file that has this on, it shows the word corretly. But when I run the jinja output template.render file, it comes out like that:

```
<h2> Produ��o </h2>
```

I've tried decoding/encoding, changing the meta `lang` and `content` to `"pt-br"`, and also using `<h2>{{"Produção"|safe}}</h2>` but nothing seems to work. Does anyone knows how I could resolve this?

My jinja2 python file goes like this:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template("layout.html")
template_vars = {
"name" : "name",
"id":123456,
"cell":"cell A"
}
html_out = template.render(template_vars)
with open("main.html", "w") as fh:
    fh.write(html_out)
```

EDIT:
Here's my head

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="pt-br" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Teste</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

EDIT 2 (SOLVED):

The problem was:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

If I take it off, it works just fine. I don't really understand why.

Comment: Make sure you've saved the template file correctly as UTF-8, and that you have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag.

Comment: @AKX it is. The funny thing is that when I open the layout.html file directly, it shows the correct characters. The problem only occurs on the output file, after I applied the jinja render function.